# Powershell results as source for SSRS/SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

As part of my job, to produce reports, I have many PowerShell scripts that I run, output to CSV, then manipulate the data into a report structure.  I would much rather be able to use this data as a source in SSRS or SQL so that I could more easily change reports, run historical reports, and let others be able to use the same data for their purposes (so I don't have to create the custom report for them.)

I have had two ideas of how to do this.  One idea, which I sure doesn't exist, would be an SSRS source (via ODBC/OLEDB/whatever will work) that can execute the PowerShell script in real time, wait for the results, and return them for the report in a table format.  This would guaranty accurate and up-to-date results.  But, like I already mentioned, I am sure this mechanism doesn't exist.

Second, run the PowerShell scripts on a regular basis, via scheduled tasks or SQL Agent, and have the script update/insert the results in a SQL table, that would then be the SSRS source.  Downside is that the results would not be real-time, but upside is that it is completely possible to do (although some examples of how to iterate through the results, with inserts or updates would help.)

Comment: I should mention that I am a jack-of-all-trades IT pro with 22 years experience.  Sys/DB/Network admin with a little developer experience (enough to know what I can't do).  I am really good at not only cutting and pasting other people's code, but generally understanding how to change it to fit what I am trying to do, so I am not looking for a complete solution, just suggestions and examples.

Comment: I think I just came up with part of my solution.  Run a stored procedure that uses xp_cmdshell to run the PowerShell script.  Now I just need some examples of the Powershell code:

one of my reports dumps info from VMware hosts into a CSV file.  I have a few examples of how to do SQL queries/inserts into a table, but what I am struggling with is how to iterate through the results from the 'get-vm', as an example, then executing a SQL insert or update on each row.

Comment: Try this too.. http://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2015/08/powershell-add-content-how-to-add-another-query-result-to-an-existing-html-report.html

Answer (score 0):

By conincidence, I came across the link below just yesterday. It details using SQL as data store for monitoring scripts and SSRS for producing reports.

https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/ebooks/tree/master/Reporting